2wan mikrotik and openvpn serveer
There is a Mikrotik router with standard settings. Connected 2 providers according to this instruction: here Everything works fine. But after connecting the 2nd provider, OpenVPN on Mikrotik stops seeing the local network of Mikrotik itself. Tell me what I forgot to add.
(Right now the rules are disabled because 2 providers are disabled) There is an opinion about the incorrect configuration of the IP route, but I don’t understand where exactly yet.
[admin@MikroTik] /ip/firewall/address-list> /ip firewall filter print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid; D - dynamic 
 0  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=forward action=passthrough 
 1    chain=input action=accept protocol=tcp src-address=21.8.0.0/24 dst-port=8291 log=no log-prefix="" 
 2    ;;; ipad admin charli
     chain=forward action=drop src-address=192.168.1.172 log=no log-prefix="" 
 3    chain=forward action=drop src-address=192.168.50.0/24 log=no log-prefix="" 
 4    ;;; defconf: accept established,related,untracked
      chain=input action=accept connection-state=established,related,untracked 
 5    chain=input action=accept protocol=tcp dst-address=ip1 dst-port=1194 log=no log-prefix="" 
 6 X  chain=input action=accept protocol=tcp dst-address=ip2 src-port="" dst-port=1194 log=no log-prefix="" 
 7    ;;; defconf: drop invalid
     chain=input action=drop connection-state=invalid log=no log-prefix="" 
 8    ;;; defconf: accept ICMP
      chain=input action=accept protocol=icmp 
 9    ;;; defconf: accept to local loopback (for CAPsMAN)
      chain=input action=accept dst-address=127.0.0.1 
10    ;;; defconf: drop all not coming from LAN
      chain=input action=drop in-interface-list=!LAN1 log=no log-prefix="" 
11    ;;; defconf: accept in ipsec policy
      chain=forward action=accept ipsec-policy=in,ipsec 
12    ;;; defconf: accept out ipsec policy
      chain=forward action=accept ipsec-policy=out,ipsec 

[admin@MikroTik] /ip/firewall/address-list> /ip firewall mangle print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid; D - dynamic 
 0  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=prerouting action=passthrough 
 1  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=forward action=passthrough 
 2  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=postrouting action=passthrough 
 3 X  chain=prerouting action=accept dst-address=gw1 in-interface=LAN log=no log-prefix="" 
 4 X  chain=prerouting action=accept dst-address=gw2 in-interface=LAN log=no log-prefix="" 
 5 X  chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=ISP1_conn passthrough=yes connection-mark=no-mark in-interface=WAN1 log=no 
      log-prefix="" 
 6 X  chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=ISP2_conn passthrough=yes connection-mark=no-mark in-interface=WAN2 log=no 
      log-prefix="" 
 7 X  chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=ISP1_conn passthrough=yes dst-address-type=!local connection-mark=no-mark 
      in-interface=LAN per-connection-classifier=both-addresses:2/0 log=no log-prefix="" 
 8 X  chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=ISP2_conn passthrough=yes dst-address-type=!local connection-mark=no-mark 
      in-interface=LAN per-connection-classifier=both-addresses:2/1 log=no log-prefix="" 
 9 X  chain=prerouting action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_ISP1 passthrough=yes connection-mark=ISP1_conn in-interface=LAN log=no log-prefix="" 
10 X  chain=prerouting action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_ISP2 passthrough=yes connection-mark=ISP2_conn in-interface=LAN log=no log-prefix="" 
11 X  chain=output action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_ISP1 passthrough=yes connection-mark=ISP1_conn log=no log-prefix="" 
12 X  chain=output action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=to_ISP2 passthrough=yes connection-mark=ISP2_conn log=no log-prefix="" 

ip route:
#      DST-ADDRESS        GATEWAY         DISTANCE
0  Xs  0.0.0.0/0          gw1            1
1  Xs  0.0.0.0/0          gw2         1
2  Xs  0.0.0.0/0          gw2         2
3  As  0.0.0.0/0          gw1           10
  DAc  ip1/32     WAN1                   0
  DIcH ip2/32  WAN2                   0
  DAc  172.16.1.0/24      LAN                    0
  DAc  192.168.1.0/24     LAN                    0
  DAc  192.168.50.0/24    LAN                    0


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
